# Symfony 2 form choice field fails validation on POST (no data class)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Here is the form in controller action:

```
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('meetings_form', 'form', $defaults)
        ->add('list','choice',array(
            'choices' => array('1'=>'val1','2'=>'val2'),
            'required' => false
        ))
        ->add('agency','text')
        ->add('name','text')
        ->add('phone','text')
        ->add('email','email')
        ->add('type','hidden')
        ->getForm();
```

Here is another action that handles POST

```
public function wsFormPostAction(Request $request)
{
    if ('POST' == $request->getMethod()) {
        $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('meetings_form', 'form')
            ->add('list', 'choice',array(
                'choices' => array()
            ))
            ->add('agency', 'text')
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('phone', 'text')
            ->add('email', 'email')
            ->add('type', 'hidden')
            ->getForm();
        $form->bind($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();
        } else {
            $errors = $form->getErrorsAsString();
            var_dump($errors);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is what I get:

> list: ERROR: This value is not valid
>   agency: No errors
>   name: No errors
>   phone: No errors
>   email: No errors
>   type: No errors

There are no examples at all with choice fields without specifying data_class.  It seems to be simple task, but I can't solve it. Why does it fails validation?

Comment: Is there a reason why your form in post is different? If I were you, I would use type class for form to have only one copy to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You pass `'choices' => array()`. This means, that no choice is valid.

Your main problem is that there's different code for creating the same form. You should use `FormType` and register it, this way you can use form builder with string argument instead of `form` in any place you need it.

Another common pattern is to use the same controller action for showing and processing the form. If there are some errors in the form, you don't need to redirect, besides, after redirect you would not be able to insert the values that were typed in the previous page.